# Latest Saved Content keeps appearing on the front-page despite being configured in "content" and "content type"

Tags: nodes

Latest saved content without the title, always appears on the front page even thought in "Content" and "Content Type" it is configured not to show up on the front-page.  The content is also disabled in the blocks, but it still appears on the front page.

Comment: Check the front-page settings. It's probably a view page, so go to that view page's settings and check filters.

Answer (score 0):

By default drupal's frontage shows latest content published on site. In drupal this is a /node path which is a view in drupal 8 and a page in drupal 7. If you are using drupal 8 it will be as easy as justmodifying the view. In drupal 7 you can set a different front page in the system configurations and the latest published won't appear any more.